# Print line based on 2nd field value, without using a loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, while-loop, ksh

I try to retrieve a line from a file without using a loop.

**myFile.txt**

```
val1;a;b;c
val2;b;d;e
val3;c;r;f
```

I would like to get the line where the second column is `b`.

If I do `grep "b" myFile.txt` then both first and second line will be outputed.

If I do `cat myFile.txt | cut -d ';' -f2 | grep "b"` then the output will just be `b` whereas I'd like to get the full line `val2;b;d;e`.

Is there a way of reaching the desired results without using a loop as below ? My file being huge it wouldn't be nice looping through it again and again.

```
while read line; do
   if [ `echo $line | cut -d ';' -f2` = "b" ]; then
      echo $line
   fi
done < myFile.txt
```

Comment: This should work: `awk -F";" '$2 == "b" {print}' myFile.txt`

Comment: Thanks it worked as desired ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your input file, The below one-liner should work:

`awk -F";" '$2 == "b" {print}' myFile.txt`

Explanation:

```
awk -F";"                    ##Field Separator as ";"
'$2 == "b"                   ##Searches for "b" in the second column($2)
{print}'                     ##prints the searched line
```

Comment: As said above thanks a lot, it worked as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Using:

1. `grep`:

   ```
   grep '^[^;]*;b;' myFile.txt
   ```
2. `sed`:

   ```
   sed '/^[^;]*;b;/!d' myFile.txt
   ```

Output is the same for both:

```
val2;b;d;e
```